# German date in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, date, phpmyadmin, date-format, date-formatting

I get the date with this code:

```
<?php $query = "SELECT `news_id`, `headline`, `category`, `body`, `date` FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC"; $news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

The date looks now like this (2012-07-24), but I need it as 24.07.2012

I already searched for a solution and tried things like this:

```
$mysql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, „%d.%m.%Y”) AS date FROM news;";
```

I don't know where to add this and what I have to change in my old code. Hope you can help.

**EDIT #1:** In phpMyAdmin the row is called 'date' and as type i use 'date'...

**EDIT #2:** I tried this

```
<?php $query = "SELECT `news_id`, `headline`, `category`, `body` FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC"; $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%d.%M.%Y\") AS `date` FROM `news`"; $news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

and the date is correct, but now I get errors:

- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$headline
- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$category
- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$body

**EDIT #3:** Yeah, I got it by myself!

```
<?php $query = "SELECT `news_id`, `headline`, `category`, `body`, DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%d.%m.%Y\") AS `date` FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC"; $news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

Bye!

Comment: Excellent! If you'd like to add that Edit #3 as your answer, you can get some points for it. If you like points. It looks like what you discovered here is that DATE_FORMAT() does not have to go right next to the SELECT. The problem with #2 is you're replacing your first query statement when you set $query again, so you lose everything from the first statement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the infos. I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution I got by myself.

**The code I got before (international date):**

```
<?php $query = "SELECT `news_id`, `headline`, `category`, `body`, `date` FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC"; $news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

**Changed code (german date):**

```
<?php $query = "SELECT `news_id`, `headline`, `category`, `body`, DATE_FORMAT(date,\"%d.%m.%Y\") AS `date` FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC"; $news_resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```